# Concept of message passing

Tags: scheme, message

I am trying to understand exactly what it does (in scheme), but it doesn't make much sense. Could somebody maybe try to explain it in simple terms? It would be greatly appreciated!

The problem in question

We will be represent a country by using these parameters: GDP in billions of 
dollars, area in millions of square miles, and population in millions. Write a message-passing procedure
(make-country-mp gdp area population) that returns an object that responds to the following messages:

• 'gdp ; simply return the gdp

• 'area ; simply return the area

• 'population ; simply return the population

• 'pop-density ; return population divided by the area

• 'gdp-per-capita ; return the gdp divided by the population

• 'is-bigger ; returns a procedure that takes in another country message-passing object and 
returns the scheme boolean true if the area of the first county (the original one) is greater than 
the area of the second country (the one being passed in), otherwise false.

**Side note:** I do have working code for the majority of the problem, but I would just like an explanation for how it works. All I had to do was follow the general form for the way that message passing works, but I dont understand any of it whatsoever. Here it is

```
(define (make-country-mp gdp area population)
    (define (dispatch msg)
      (cond ((equal? msg 'gdp) gdp)
        ((equal? msg 'area) area)
        ((equal? msg 'population) population)
        ((equal? msg 'pop-density) (/ population area))
        ((equal? msg 'gdp-per-capita) (/ gdp population))
       ;((equal? msg 'is-bigger) ; unsure of the code here
        (else (error "invalid option" msg)))) 
     dispatch)
```

Comment: hmm... can you give us more context? In general, the term message-passing is used in many different situations. Most generally, it refers to ... components that pass messages. That wasn't very helpful, I'm afraid. More context from you?

Comment: Alright. Because I don't have the slightest clue of what I'm looking at, I will just provide an example from a homework problem that I was given. Of course I'm not looking for an answer by any means, just an explanation of the concept, which might make more sense to you given this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `make-country-mp` returns a function object (a closure, in this case, which remembers the values for `gdp`, `area`, and `population` that were passed into the `make-country-mp` call), which you can call with one argument. The argument is matched against the symbols `gdp`, `area`, `population`, `pop-density`, `gdp-per-capita`, and `is-bigger`, and the appropriate result is returned in each case.

If you know `case`, you may find that easier to read:

```
(define (make-country-mp gdp area population)
  (lambda (msg)
    (case msg
      ((gdp) gdp)
      ((area) area)
      ((population) population)
      ((pop-density) (/ population area))
      ((gdp-per-capita) (/ gdp population))
      ((is-bigger) (lambda (rhs)
                     (> area (rhs 'area))))
      (else (error "invalid option" msg)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I definitely understand it better now. However, what does rhs mean in your lambda?

Comment: "rhs" usually means right hand side. Notice that `rhs` is used to get the right hand argument in `(> area (rhs 'area))`. To make the right-handedness even clearer, pretend that we can use infix notation like `area  > (rhs 'area)`

Comment: @user2789945 To add to c45207's comment, to make it even more infix-like, you can look at it as the equivalent of `lambda rhs: area > rhs.area()` (Python syntax). (And yes, I did intend `rhs` to mean right-hand side.)